# Parametric primitives through python script

Tags: python, geometry

I'm trying to get into blender Scripting and am having a hard time finding examples or info on how one would create something like 3DS Max's Scripted Primitive; parametric objects that can be modified at any time after creation, not only until you perform another action, like standard blender object.

Main thing is I want to generate geonetry through code, not with blend shapes or by simply moving components around, and I want to be able to go back at any time and adjust this geometry.

Ideally there's an example script out there that does something similar, I'm experienced enough with Python to figure it out, it's just documentation is very lacking and I find info on google that is over 10 years old!

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. "Archimesh" add-on has this functionality and it's quite up-to date. You can start by looking its code.

Comment: Am I missing something? When I create an Archimesh cabinet, I can only modify the parameters right after it's created. Once I do anything else, it becomes unchangeable, just a collection of meshes with no more params.

Comment: Can you please add a link, or a short precise to describe  a 3ds max scripted primitive. [Scripted SimpleObject plugin???](https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2016/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_C0BFFE27_BB59_4265_8F70_BFE8A636F7CB_htm)  to get latest search results:  [How to filter google search results by date](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/142143?hl=en)

Comment: For the cabinet there is no option yet, but if you try with the door, the wall or the windows, you'll have objects driven by parameters (bottom of the properties panel).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're still searching for this but I found something that may be what you're looking for. It's an Add-On called "Wonder Mesh". The Add-On allows you to generate and edit the parameters of its available primitives. That being said, the author states that you need to convert the object to a "regular mesh" if you want to modify the primitive. It overwrites modifications to the Object Data that were made in Edit Mode.

**Here is a direct link to the Add-On**:

https://blendermarket.com/products/wonder-mesh

*(You can purchase it here or go to the bottom of the page for the GitHub link)*

**Here is a video on the most recent version for Blender v2.8**:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUFWcGAoDPw

Here is a video on a older version (in case it's useful):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCnwnwuDbfk

Comment: Hello and welcome, thanks for the answer. You should probably post links to where one can directly get said addon.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. The links that I posted are to videos from the author of the add-on and the videos include the links to the download in the descriptions of them. I'll update my post and include the most recent link though.