# How to get an Operator update (not re-create) an object/mesh when changing parameters

Tags: python, mesh

I'm having a problem updating a mesh after initial creation. I like to create a mesh in one step and update it's vertices afterwards, without completely recreating the mesh.

After several iterations I trimmed the code down to a minimum (below) and it doesn't seem to work...
I'm setting a custom property ("update") to the active object and print "create", if the "update" property exists I print "update". The code does not seem to take the update-branch and the property does not seem to be set. If I de-select the object and execute the Operator again, the property is set.

What am I missing? Do I need to update the object? Is there another way of doing this?

```py
def execute(self, context):

        print(context.active_object.data.keys())

        currentObject = context.active_object

        if ('mesh_update' in currentObject.data.keys()):
            print("update")
        else:
            currentObject.data["update"] = True
            print("create")

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

**Additional information**

The operator is called from "add object" menu (the one using shift + a).
I also tried an operator property, a group property for objects in general and some other possibilities for days now.
The operator property does not work because this setting has to be object (or mesh?) specific and this setting would be carried to the next object the operator gets applied to. Pre defined object properties have the same effect as the dynamic one in the example code above.

**Update #1**

I handled my problem in a different way now by using a local variable inside the operator to switch between the "create" and "update" stages. This eliminates some other issues and is easier to work with. I had my code working this way some iterations ago while searching for a solution.
This leads to maybe the base problem I am trying so solve here: my active object changes between those stages! I explicitly set my newly created object to be the active one but as soon as hitting FINISHED and the operator's execute method starting over again (with the new stage "update"!) the active object changes.

```py
updateMesh = False

def execute(self, context):
        use_enter_edit_mode = context.preferences.edit.use_enter_edit_mode
        context.preferences.edit.use_enter_edit_mode = False

        if context.mode == "EDIT_MESH":
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

        currentObject = context.active_object
        # THE "OLD"/INITIALLY ACTIVE OBJECT IS PRINTED HERE ON THE VERY FIRST RUN
        print(currentObject)

        if self.updateMesh == True:
            # ERROR
            # THE "OLD"/INITIALLY ACTIVE OBJECT IS PRINTED HERE
            # NOT THE NEW ONE FROM BELOW
            print("update " + currentObject.name)
        else:
            self.updateMesh = True
            # A NEW OBJECT IS CREATED HERE, LINKED TO VIEW LAYER
            # AND SET AS ACTIVE VIEW LAYER OBJECT
            # OUTPUTS THE NEW OBJECT
            print("create " + currentObject.name)

        if use_enter_edit_mode:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
        # restore pre operator state
        context.preferences.edit.use_enter_edit_mode = use_enter_edit_mode

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

**Update #2**

Here is a complete working example. Setup is like this:

1. execute the script below
2. Window > Toggle System Console
3. create an object (Monkey/Suzanne for example)
4. while object selected press SHIFT + A
5. select Mesh > Object Update Test (car icon...)
6. edit parameter (Dummy Property)

What it does:

- Suzanne is the active object
- an object "NewObject" is created and set active
- changing the property "Dummy Property" removes "NewObject" and sets Suzanne active again

What it SHOULD do:

- keep the object and show "update NewObject" when changing the property

````py
import bpy
import bmesh

from bpy.utils import ( register_class, unregister_class )
from bpy.props import ( BoolProperty, FloatProperty )
from bpy.types import Operator
from mathutils import Vector

class ObjectUpdateOperator(Operator):
    bl_idname = "mesh.objectupdatetest"
    bl_label = "Object Update Test"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'} #, 'PRESET'}

    dummyProp : FloatProperty(
        name = "Dummy Property",
        default = 0.2,
        min = 0.0001,
        max = 10000.0,
        precision = 4,
        step = 4,
        )

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        box = layout.box()
        box.label(text="Basic Parameters")
        box.prop(self, 'dummyProp')

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.scene is not None

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.execute(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    updateMesh = False

    def execute(self, context):
        use_enter_edit_mode = context.preferences.edit.use_enter_edit_mode
        context.preferences.edit.use_enter_edit_mode = False

        if context.mode == "EDIT_MESH":
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

        currentObject = context.active_object
        
        # problematic part...
        if self.updateMesh == True: # update object/mesh
            print("update " + currentObject.name)
        
        else: # create object/mesh
            print("create")
            print("active object: " + currentObject.name)
            new_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("NewMesh")
            new_verts = [
                Vector((-1, 1, 0)),
                Vector((1, 1, 0)),
                Vector((1, -1, 0)),
                Vector((-1, -1, 0)),
            ]

            new_faces = [[0, 1, 2, 3]]
            new_mesh.from_pydata(new_verts, [], new_faces)
            new_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="NewObject", object_data=new_mesh)
            view_layer = context.view_layer
            view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection.objects.link(new_object)
            view_layer.objects.active = None
            new_object.select_set(True)
            view_layer.objects.active = new_object
            print("NEW active object: " + context.active_object.name)
            self.updateMesh = True


        if use_enter_edit_mode:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
        # restore pre operator state
        context.preferences.edit.use_enter_edit_mode = use_enter_edit_mode

        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_item(self, context):
    # we need at minimum one object selected!
    if len(context.selected_objects) == 0:
        return

    layout = self.layout
    layout.operator("mesh.objectupdatetest", text="Object Update Test", icon="AUTO")


# register and unregister
classes = (
    ObjectUpdateOperator,
)

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)    
    # add menu to shift-a add object menu
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.append(menu_item)
    
def unregister():
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)    
    # remove menu item
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.remove(menu_item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: A parametric approach is good ol' chestnut. Once a primitive is created only the name is an indicator of origins. (if not changed as well)  Possible dupe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101141/parametric-primitives-through-python-script ??

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I think the problem is more fundamental. Something seems to block the properties from updating if I set them by code.
If I set a property of an object it even shows up correctly inside the "Item" panel under "Properties" but if I try to access this property it seems like it has not been set!
If I deselect the object and run the code/operator again the property gets recognized.

Comment: IMO issue commented is  same as here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181649/replicate-value-stored-in-object-into-properties-of-new-one  The execute is undoing redoing as settings are changing.

Comment: Thank you, batFINGER, for those suggestions. Maybe I only don't understand what is done in those posts but I didn't get my problem fixed.

Comment: @batFINGER I've updated me description and code above. Please see the code comments.

Comment: @batFINGER I've added a working example to copy&paste in combination with a detailed description. There must be something I don't understand about how blender is handling things...

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what I am missing... either it is a bug in Blender or I don't understand the whole mechanism of Blender (and python?).

Comment: No it's not a bug in blender it's how blender operators work.. As a little test hit G and move the cube, in rotation properties change a setting, then in the Move operators  redo panel change an operator property, the rotation will be reverted to what it was. _ie_ the state when blender was invoked.  IMO you are going to go around in a circle trying to change this behaviour.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification. So there is no workaround for this?

Comment: I did some more research to find a solution to my initial problem. Could either "shape keys" or "drivers" change the mesh (vertices) after creating in an "update branch" of the operator? Or maybe even changing the operator of the created object?